# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider' to 'WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following insdie my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {


            ExtendedMembershipProvider domainProvider;

           domainProvider = Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
```

but i am getting the folloiwng error :-

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider' to
>   'WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider'. An explicit conversion
>   exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all: " An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)":

```
ExtendedMembershipProvider domainProvider;
domainProvider = (ExtendedMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["TestDomain1ADMembershipProvider"];
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this will raise the following exception "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider' to type 'WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider'."

Comment: @johnG: then you should edit your question and show your web.config. I assume `ExtendedMembershipProvider` is a custom class that inherits `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider`, isn't it?